# Downgrade Ruby on Mac OS X for Jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, jekyll

I am trying to install Jekyll on my Mac but I currently get the following error:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

My friend was able to successfully install it with the following ruby version `ruby 2.0.0p648`

I have `ruby 2.3.1p112` and get an error so I am assuming I need to downgrade my Ruby.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I can successfully install on 2.3.1p112. A bit more context to your error might help - what did you execute, and is there any more of the output? Also, downgrading is an overkill: use `rvm` or `rbenv` to have multiple Ruby versions.

Comment: @Amadan I literally just did `gem install jekyll` and get *only* the error noted above. I'm not quite sure what to do next. I to install and use `rvm` but get `shell_session_update: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I had to use the following command to get it to work:

```
sudo gem update --system
```